# How can i create animated bar chart using plotly?

Tags: python, data-visualization

[image]
I have csv file with represents rating of website and reasons why users gave from 1 to 10 stars. I want it to be in animated bar chart, where x will represent reasons, y will represent count of stars by reason and it will be animated by peoples rate (from 1 to 10 stars)

example:
[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to do, so I'd like to be sure, what keys are you referring to that would be animated?

Comment: In the example i provided there are years from 1952 to 2007, so i want it the same but with 1stars, 2stars,..., 10stars. Sorry if it's unclear, i'm not as fluent in english, as i want it to be